# ObjectContext is leaking memory for detached entities

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, memory-leaks

I already checked this using a memory profiler and there are no real entities which stay in memory **but** hash-sets, dictionaries and EntityKey objects -- but I found no way how to disconnect these references.

So simple question: How do I stop the context (or its ObjectStateManager) from **growing infinitely** in size?

*[And yes, I know that long living contexts should be avoided, but in this case it's one complex analysis run which needs several hierarchical data being loaded (and the sample below is just a minimal problem demonstration) so finally it is a "short" living one-operation context.]*

Steps to repro:

- create a new console application
- create a EF model for a Northwind database (either use some real SQL Server or copy Northwind.sdf from Compact Samples folder)
- use code below:

Code [Updated, doesn't need real DB connection anymore]:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const double MiB = 1024 * 1024;
        using ( var context = new NorthwindEntities() )
        {
            var last = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / MiB;
            Console.WriteLine("before run: {0:n3} MiB", last);
            var id = 0;
            while ( true )
            {
                Run(context, ref id);

                GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                var current = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / MiB;
                Console.WriteLine("after run: {0:n3} MiB (+{1:n3} MiB)", current, current - last);
                last = current;

                if ( Console.KeyAvailable )
                    break;
                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 100));
            }
        }
    }

    static void Run(NorthwindEntities context, ref int id)
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
        {
            var category = new Category { Category_ID = ++id };
            category.EntityKey = new EntityKey("NorthwindEntities.Categories", "Category_ID", id);
            var product = new Product { Product_ID = id, Category_ID = id };
            product.EntityKey = new EntityKey("NorthwindEntities.Products", "Product_ID", id);
            product.Category = category;
            context.Attach(product);
            context.Detach(product);
            context.Detach(category);
        }

        var ctr = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enumerating living/attached objects:");
        const EntityState AllStates = EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Unchanged;
        foreach ( var entry in context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(AllStates) )
            Console.WriteLine("  #{0} [{1}] {2}", ++ctr, entry.EntityKey, entry.Entity);
        if ( ctr == 0 )
            Console.WriteLine("  NOTHING (as expected)");
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, what were your results? Did you use a Memory profiler?

Comment: How many runs and how many minutes to reach 0.1 / 0.5 / 1.0 / 1.5 GB?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Yes I used Memory profiler, just see the very first sentence. My sample has very poor performance using SQL Server Compact but the real app is using SQLite which can save 10,000 new entities on each ``SaveChanges()`` in 10% of the time and so it didn't take long till a complete 1 GiB has been wasted for nothing. The sample here looses ~0.5MiB per run.

Comment: I updated the sample so it now leaks ~18 MiB every 10 seconds.

Comment: Fwiw, I did confirm the results of your previous version. I think you should just refactor and redesign to use shorter lived Contexts.

Comment: But doesn't this render the feature of detaching entities useless?

Comment: I mainly use detached objects in ASP.NET and WCF projects. The feature is for transporting objects to different Contexts, not to manually manage memory. Contexts are meant to be short-lived, don't fight it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I'm only detaching entities directly after having called SaveChanges(), I'm now counting the number of detached entities and when the counter reaches 10,000 I detach all still living (and needed) objects from the context and create a new context to which I attach all detached objects.
Downside: The IsLoaded property of EntityReferences and EntityCollections is now always false (but I don't rely on this).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that detach is meant to remove the context from the entity, not the entity from the context. Don't trust the context to remove references to entities(or their internals).

I agree this leakage is a problem, but a lot of people(myself included) have tried and failed to prevent EF contexts from growing indefinitely(as long as queries are being run).

As a proposed solution, perhaps instead of relying on the database as a "working space" for your calculations, it might be possible to recreate database structure in your own in-memory representation, work on that, and then translate back into db.  You could use temporary files if you have a lot of data.

This should have the effect of shortening lifespan of contexts.

Alternatively, maybe consider using something else other than EF(at least for the processing intensive parts), since it may not be suited to your situation. Perhaps something lower level, like a DataReader would be more suitable for your situation.

Comment: I would have to duplicate nearly everything which just is the heart of EF: Automatically connecting all 1:1 and 1:n relationships on load and tracking every change which should be written back to the store.